# Change of an ausbildung visa into student visa without completing ausbildung in Germany

Tags: visa

My son went to Germany with a student visa and later changed to an ausbildung visa. Are there any barriers to changing this ausbildung visa again to a student visa if he gets admission to a college/university before completing that ausbildung(apprenticeship) in Germany?

Comment: Other than the barrier of justifying why he qualifies, given he’d have abandoned two study courses?